# C library to easily create interactive shell

Tags: c, parsing, shell, command

I want to create a program like gdb or gnuplot that has it's own command prompt. I'm looking for a library that will handle the parsing/input validation as well as provide a command history. So far googling for this topic is difficult because any search with the terms 'c' and 'shell' will only produce results for 'csh'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recommend [CLI parser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cliparser/). It is quite suited for your described use case.

> CLI Parser provides a framework for quickly development of Cisco-like CLI commands. It provides a simple syntax to define CLI commands, a compiler to automatically convert these commands into a C parse tree and a run-time library to create CLI.

Answer (score 3):

History is usually managed by [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) or [libedit](http://www.thrysoee.dk/editline/). Parsing is usually done with [flex](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/)/[bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/).

Comment: I've used both of these technologies before (separately), but the work required to glue them together is still significant. I'm specifically looking for a way to just have a library automatically generate a parser based on function prototypes.